# Pyinstaller + Z3-solver problem (hidden console)

Tags: tkinter, pyinstaller, z3, z3py

Hello I am working on tkinter application. In my application I got button. After pressing this button I am doing some z3-solver stuff. My problem is that I wanted to create exe file by using Pyinstaller. I run this console command and everything worked fine.

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon icon.ico main.py --collect-all z3-solver --collect-all ttkbootstrap --collect-all z3
```

But I wanted to hide console, so I run command with -w flag:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon icon.ico main.py --collect-all z3-solver --collect-all ttkbootstrap --collect-all z3 -w
```

My problem is that second exe file (with hidden console) doesnt doing z3-solver stuff after pressing button and I dont know why.

## UPDATE

I found out that in exe file with hidden console I was getting error: **'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'**.

Problem was in code like that:

```
b = Bool("b")
```

I still dont undestand why exe file with console worked fine and second one (without console) thew error.

Comment: create a [mre].

Comment: I know doesn’t solve your issue directly but I had a similar issue and switched to generating an exe with  nuitka and all was OK

Comment: @Alexander I added some new information about my problem